# what type-conversion is taking place when a boolean value used to construct a string object?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, type-conversion

In my code, there was a typo:  instead of using `"false"` while initializing a `std::string` object, I typed `false` (which is a `bool`). Now this did not report any compilation error. But later in my code, when this string-object is being used, I get `std::logic_error` during runtime. Can anyone please explain, why the construction was allowed in this case (else I would have received a compilation error and found the problem there) ?

Here is a small snippet -

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{

   std::string str = false;

   std::cout << str << "\n";

}
```

The o/p that i get while running this -

```
xhdrdevl8@~/MYBACKUP=>g++ -o test_string -g test_string.cxx

xhdrdevl8@~/MYBACKUP=>./test_string

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
Aborted
```

Answer (score 8):

`std::string` has a constructor that takes a `const char*` to a null-terminated string.

`false` can be used as a null-pointer constant because it is an integral constant expression with a value of zero, so this `std::string` constructor is used.

Passing a null pointer to this constructor yields undefined behavior.  Your Standard Library implementation helps you out here by generating a `logic_error` exception to inform you that you have violated the constraints of the `std::string` constructor by passing it a null pointer.  Other implementations may not be so helpful (you might get an immediate crash or data corruption or who knows what).

Comment: ok. But shouldn't this have resulted in a compile-time error? (instead of catching the error later during runtime)

Comment: @anindita:  No.  `false` is usable as a null pointer constant (just like `0` is or `NULL` is if you `#include <cstddef>`) and a null pointer constant can be used as a `const char*`, so the `std::string` constructor taking a `const char*` can be used.